# How can a new programmer work from home as a freelancer

Tags: freelance-websites, programmer

I'm a new programmer who lost his job(in a different field) recently due to a health issue. Now I can work from home only. So being a programmer I think it could be possible but since I'm new(21/male) I don't have any experience that where should I start from and try to get one. Could you help me please and give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

You need customer(s). In order to get them, you need a reason for them to hire you. Among those are:

1) You have specific skills and can document successful deliveries
2) You are cheap

In the first case, you could attempt directly contacting potential customers. Most often, this leads to a large amount of non-responses and outright rejections - which may be disheartening when starting out.

Instead, you could hire others to do the cold-calling and have them book meetings with potential clients where you then by yourself attempt to sell your services. This approach assumes you have at least a little money to begin with.

Alternatively, you can 'bid' for clients via a portal like Upwork - with which I have no experience, but suppose price is the primary parameter. This is probably the cheapest way to get started from scratch.

Having established a good relationship with a client, they might ask you to perform work outside your comfort zone. Never turn those requests down out-of-hand, but make an honest assessment of whether this is something you could undertake. Clients might hire you for technical skills, but they most often keep you for other reasons such as a friendly, professional problem-solving attitude.

Comment: Your profile says you're a freelancer. What are some sites that you work at?

Comment: I'm a freelance contractor, meaning I work full-time at one large corporate client at a time. Basically, I get work by being contacted by consultancies whom I bill even though I'm on-site at the end client.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think this question is answerable...

However, consider that to be a freelancer it entails some **good non-directed problem solving abilities**. You don't have anyone standing over you telling you what to do or how to work out an issue. It's in your hands to have enough deductive reasoning abilities to come to solutions when necessary.

Finding work would seem to me to be the #1 problem **all** freelancers face. How you solve that problem for your skill set and abilities can be, and often is, *wildly different* than how I may solve that problem.

There are many, many, many paths to finding work...

- Online crowdsourcing
- Subcontracting
- Friends and family
- Small business leagues
- Chambers of Congress
- Word of Mouth
- Direct advertising (on or off line)

Often many are aware of these avenues but for one reason or another don't "feel" like venturing into them. One has to ask how serious you are about being a freelancer if you are sitting around merely waiting for work to fall into your lap.

A simple web search for "freelance work" will turn up many crowdsource web sites. Narrow your search more and you may get better results.

Telling *everyone* you know you are searching for freelance projects in the field of XXXXX can often lead to someone thinking "Hey, John Doe was just asking me about that.".

Attending SBA or COC meetings in your area and getting familiar with the *business owners* there may lead to work.

Basically... you have to hustle. It is not going to merely "happen" for you. And, to be a bit blunt... if you have to ask where to get work.. you may not be cut out for freelancing, since that is the #1 issue all freelancers must solve.

Answer (score 0):

short answer - register to famous freelancing site (there are plenty, I do personally recommend upwork.com) , follow the rules of the specific site and apply to the jobs that you really can accomplish only, but apply as much as you can without dissapointment , having in mind always that first job is the hardest one.

Comment: Do you work for upwork.com?

Comment: yup, quite long time